# How to fix this layout issue in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I created a popup with a listview inside. I also applied a list filter. However, it is not correctly formatted. Is there any way I can push it up a bit (like a list divider would be)?

EDIT: the code

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="symptomslist" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d" data-filter="true">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: The filter items field is not properly positioned]

Comment: Wrap them with div data-role=content

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, didn't work though.

Comment: Not the popup, the content inside it.

Comment: Thanks man, you've answered my question before and once again, thank you so much for your patience with a JQM noobie :)

Comment: We are here to help, guide and assist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get best results of jQuery Mobile styles of contents inside page, dialog, panel or popup, always place them inside `data-role="content"`.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-filter="true">
      <!-- list items -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ThzP2/)**